# Sum values in column that match selected value in other column

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

How can I get the sum of values from the column "Quantity" that match a selected value in the column "Le Nom". For example :

```
Le Nom      Quantity
HEA200      200
HEB300      150
IPE450      700
HEA200      300
```

Let's say that the first row is selected, I want to sum the first one (200) and the fourth one (300) since they share the same value (HEA200).

Here is my code to get the sum of all values, but I can't achieve my goal.

```
int sum = 0;

string NameProfil = 
    gridView2.GetRowCellValue(gridView2.FocusedRowHandle, "Le Nom").ToString();

for (int i = 0; i < gridView2.RowCount; i++) 
{
    sum += int.Parse(Convert.ToString(gridView2.GetRowCellValue(i, "Quantité")));
}

MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString() + " "+ NameProfil);
```

Comment: You need to GroupBy first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
string NameProfil = gridView2.GetRowCellValue(gridView2.FocusedRowHandle, "Le Nom").ToString();

for (int i = 0; i < gridView2.RowCount; i++) 
{
    if(gridView2.GetRowCellValue(i, "Le Nom").ToString() == NameProfil)
    {
        sum += int.Parse(gridView2.GetRowCellValue(i, "Quantité").ToString());
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(sum + " "+ NameProfil);
```

should do the trick.

Also, `.ToString()` will be implicitly called on `sum` when trying to concatenate it with `strings`, so - while not incorrect - it is not needed.

Comment: i add .ToString() :sum += int.Parse(gridView2.GetRowCellValue(i, "Quantité").ToString());

Comment: @M.Bouabdallah Well you're right, in my head `int.Parse` could take other stuff than `string`, but I was wrong. I edited my answer in consequence

Comment: can you help me to get this code work on click of the button,Now i use it on ValidateRow event ,i try to make two loop but i maked the code too messy,thanks in advance.